# Simultaneously entering into two states when using the statemachine pub package?

Tags: dart, state-machine, dart-pub

I have this use-case where I need the state machine to remain in a general state while switching between smaller, more specific states. Is this possible using the statemachine pub package?

Comment: This is a very specific question to the package. I suggest to create an issue in the GitHub source repo (with a link to this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you could define a nested state-machine that gets started and does its own thing when the parent enters a specific state.

In fact, I think it would be easy to add first-class composition of state machines to the library. I will try to address your [feature request](https://github.com/renggli/dart-statemachine/issues/1) in one of the upcoming releases, but I am also happy to review a pull request.